# REST: Retrieving a list of all databases a user can access (inconsistency?)

Tags: rest, arangodb

The documentation states that the list of all databases a user can access can be retrieved using: http://localhost:8529/_api/database/user.
However that gives me a 401 when I try it.

Moreover, the Swagger documentation inside the graphical interface, when I click on 'Try it out' it uses the following URL: http://localhost:8529/_db/test_db_2/_api/database/user

Which I find weird since it contains the name of the database: `test_db_2`

Is there a way to query for all the databases a user can access without knowing their names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we have several things here.

First off: ArangoDB 3.0 defaults to enabled authentication. That means you have to provide authentication headers to any http request. If you opened that URL in the browser or via curl this is likely to fail. When using curl you can for example pass the --user parameter to specify username/password. If you omit authentication the server will always send a 401 http response.

Now to your usecase: Getting the allowed databases per user can be achieved in the following way:

`curl -v --user root:8bYikSrSC2ue5zlw 172.17.0.2:8529/_api/user/testuser/database`

This is a full example for a running docker instance on my machine. Replace testuser with your desired user, replace host/port and username/password. Note that "/database" is static. By providing this you are telling ArangoDB to provide a list of databases the user has access to. Example result:

`{"result":{"test":"rw","test2":"rw"},"error":false,"code":200}`

Lastly ArangoDB offers its REST API on a per database level. By specifying /_db/test_db_2 you are accessing the REST API within database test_db_2. Without specifying a database (accessing /_api/something directly) you are implictly asking ArangoDB to operate within the internal _system database. You probably selected the database test_db_2 when you logged into ArangoDB and so the API links in the UI are pointing to that database.

The /user API is somewhat special because users are global and so it doesn't really matter which database you specify.